# C# how to check if base class is instance of derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

How to check from within the base class if it is an instance of a derived class:

```
class A0 : A {};
class A1 : A {};
class A2 : A {};

class A 
{
    void CheckDerived() 
    {
        if (this is A0) 
        {
            //Do something when instance is A0
        } 
        else if (this is A1) 
        {
            //Do something when instance is A1
        } 
        else if (this is A2) 
        {
            //Do something when instance is A2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very bad practice FYI, it would be better to have a virtual method which all of the derived classes override.

Comment: A base-class should never know anything of its derived ones. What would you do if there are no such children?

Comment: @DannyGoodall said just what I was thinking.  Don't even try this.

Comment: Well, this code should work, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Make the method virtual and override it. Anywhere where you have type-checking blocks like that is code smell.

Comment: Why do you need this? What´s your *actual* goal? Maybe there´s a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Class A has several childs, so am trying something like this to avoid overrides for each derived class. But it seems override is the correct way.

Comment: Why do you want to know if your instance even *is* a child and not the base-class? That sounds pretty odd to me.

Comment: Well, what would happen when you add class A4, A5, and A6? you will have to write their logic into class A... When using override, class A never have to change when you add derived classes. This is the [open/close principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) in action.

Comment: @HimBromBeere class A listen to user action, the response depends in what derived class is.

Comment: _"so am trying something like this to avoid overrides for each derived class"_ - WHY? Exactly this is where overrides come in handy!

Comment: That sounds like you should override the response-handler in every derived class.

Comment: I'm with Fildor. This is the very reason why overriding members exists in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in the question should do what you want, however, as Danny Goodball wrote in his comment, this is a very bad practice.

According to the [open/close principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), stating that "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification",
The proper way to handle different actions for different children is using override:

Make the method virtual (might be even better as an abstract method), and override it in each derived class with it's own implementation:

```
class A
{
     virtual void CheckDerived() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class A0 : A
{
     override void CheckDerived() { Console.WriteLine("A0"); }
}

class A1 : A
{
     override void CheckDerived() { Console.WriteLine("A1"); }
}
```

Comment: While @mostafa answer works too for what I need (hard for me to explain, since English isn't my first language), am selecting this as the correct answer for being the correct practice.

Comment: I believe override should go before void, not after?

Comment: @Lou Thanks for finding my typo from 3 years ago :-)

Comment: No prob :). I only noticed because I tried it myself not realising there was a proper order, and Visual Studio complained at me!

Comment: What if there are some special behavior in each of the derived class? That way it's necessary to check and cast to a derived class instance to invoke that special behavior. Or does this situation imply some code smell?

Comment: No, the virtual / override mechanism does that for you - if your reference is of type `A` but the instance is of type `A1`, the method that will be invoked is the `A1` met, that's the point of override.

Answer (score -1):

you should do this using class types and IsAssignableFrom method

```
  public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    A a = new A0();
    a.CheckDerived();

 }
}

class A0 : A {};
class A1 : A {};
class A2 : A {};
class A {
public void CheckDerived() {
    if(this.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(A0))) Console.Write("A0");
    if(this.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(A1))) Console.Write("A1");
    if(this.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(A2))) Console.Write("A2");
}
}
```

Comment: No, you should never do that.

Comment: @HimBromBeere why?

Comment: Because you introduce hard dependencies. What if there are more children than A0-2? What if I want to retire A1 and remove it from code base? What if I want to add A3? What if a _coworker_ wants to add A3 ... Also, you define behavior of children inside the parent ... I could go on and on and on ... Open/Closed ... Testing ...

Comment: He just wants to know how can get type of object in base class, there is many reasons that you need this, first for example when want to compare two object types, or when you want to create a dynamic expression or when want to load your plugins

Comment: Read the comments ... he is trying to define responses depending on derived type. - Which is exactly the use case for an override.

Comment: @mostafa yes, your answer works for what I need, but also because I wanted to know how to compare from base to derived. Thanks.